# Get a specific word out of a String with regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have an String

```
String string = "-minY:50 -maxY:100 -minVein:8 -maxVein:10 -meta:0 perChunk:5;";
```

And I want to somehow get the -meta:0 out of it with regex (replace everything except -meta:0), I made an regex which deletes -meta:0 but I can't make it delete everything except -meta:0
I tried using some other regex but it was ignoring whole line when I had -meta:[0-9] in it, and like you can see I have one line for everything.
This is how it has been deleting -meta:0 from the String:

```
String meta = string.replaceAll("( -meta:[0-9])", "");
System.out.println(meta);
```

I just somehow want to reverse that and delete everything except -meta:[0-9]

I couldn't find anything on the page about my issue because everything was ignoring whole line after it found the word, so sorry if there's something similar to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be capturing your match in a captured group and use it's reference in replacement as:

```
String meta = string.replaceAll("^.*(-meta:\\d+).*$", "$1");
System.out.println(meta);
//=> "-meta:0"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JDTL46/5)

Comment: Thank you looks like it worked. I was just getting illegal escape character in string literal error because I needed "\\d" instead of "\d" to escape

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your requirement you want to :

a) you want to extract `meta*` from the string

b) replace everything else with `""`

You could do something like :

```
String string = "-minY:50 -maxY:100 -minVein:8 -maxVein:10 -meta:0 perChunk:5;";


Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(-meta:[0-9]).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);

if ( m.find() )
{
    string = string.replaceAll(m.group(0),m.group(1));

    System.out.println("After removal of meta* : " + string);
}
```

What this code does is it finds `meta:[0-9]` and retains it and removes other found groups

Comment: The problem with this it to outputs: "After removal of meta* : -meta:0|-meta:0|-meta:0|-meta:0" instead of just "After removal of meta* : -meta:0", anubhava's answer helped me but this can still work too

Comment: I don't see how it can print "-meta:0|-meta:0|-meta:0|-meta:0"? What was your input string?

Comment: hm... looks like I was maybe inputting the wrong String. Everything works with this too, sorry my bad! I'll use the mix of anubhava's and yours because I will find it useful in some cases.